# Webscraping with Selenium and Pandas don't show dataframe values on csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, export-to-csv

Below code is a transformed sample of the original but it describes
the problem as well. In my project I am using Selenium to collect data, then clicking
the statistics button and let pandas libraries to read page source. After some lines
of manipulation I have the desired dataframe. The problem is at the exporting procedure,
since despite the data from selectors are perfectly writed in csv, the dataframe values
displayed as zeros.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pandas as pd
import re

errors = []
season = []

my_url = f'https://www.mackolik.com/mac/bayern-m%C3%BCnchen-vs-augsburg/2mck8cqve7nadhtfff65a1mhg'
option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(5)


#scraping
try:
        date_elm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
                        "//p[@class='p0c-soccer-match-details-header__info']//span[@class='p0c-soccer-match-details-header__info-date']").get_attribute('data-utc')
        ts = int(date_elm)
        ts /=1000
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        
        info_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "p[class='p0c-soccer-match-details-header__info']").text
        info = info_bar.split('|')
        day = info[2]
        matchday = re.findall("\d+", day)[0]
        crowd = info[3]
        attedance = crowd[crowd.find('(')+1:crowd.find(')')]
        home_team = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".p0c-soccer-match-details-header__team-name.p0c-soccer-match-details-header__team-name--home").text
        away_team = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".p0c-soccer-match-details-header__team-name.p0c-soccer-match-details-header__team-name--away").text
        
        home_score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                ".p0c-soccer-match-details-header__score-home").text
        away_score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                ".p0c-soccer-match-details-header__score-away").text
        
        ht_scoreA = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                "(//div[@class='p0c-soccer-match-details-header__detailed-score'])[1]").text
        ht_scoreB = split_string = re.split(r'[(-) ]', ht_scoreA)
        home_htscore = ht_scoreB[2]
        away_htscore = ht_scoreB[4]
        referee = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                "li[class='p0c-match-officials__official-list-item p0c-match-officials__official-list-item--main '] span[class='p0c-match-officials__official-name']").text
        
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
                    By.LINK_TEXT, "İstatistik")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
        sleep(10)
        
        
        dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
        gentab = dfs[0]
        gentab = gentab.replace('%','', regex=True)
        gentab.drop(gentab.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)
        general = gentab.iloc[[0, 10]]
        general.columns = ['team1', 'team2']
        pastab = dfs[1]
        pastab = pastab.replace('%','', regex=True)
        pastab.drop(pastab.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)
        passes = pastab.iloc[[6, 8]]
        passes.columns = ['team1', 'team2']
        att_tab = dfs[2]
        att_tab = att_tab.replace('%','', regex=True)
        att_tab.drop(att_tab.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)
        attack = att_tab.iloc[[10, 8, 4]]
        attack.columns = ['team1', 'team2']
        foul_tab = dfs[4]
        foul_tab = foul_tab.replace('%','', regex=True)
        foul_tab.drop(foul_tab.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)
        fouls = foul_tab.iloc[[0, 2, 4]]
        fouls.columns = ['team1', 'team2']
        stats = pd.concat([general, passes, attack, fouls], ignore_index=True)
        stats.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        stats = stats.assign(sts=['Possesion','Corners','Attack_Passes','Centres',
                     'Short_Shots','Long_Shots','Target_Shots','Fouls','Yellows',
                     'Reds'])
        stats.columns = [home_team, away_team, 'sts']
        stats = stats.reindex(columns=[home_team, 'sts', away_team])
        driver.quit()
        
except:
        driver.quit()

    
        # Handling the stats
home_stats = {}
away_stats = {}
    
home_series = stats[home_team]
away_series = stats[away_team]
stats_series = stats['sts']
    
for row in zip(home_series, stats_series, away_series):
            stat = row[1].replace(' ', '_').lower()
            home_stats[stat] = row[0]
            away_stats[stat] = row[2]
    
stats_check = ['Yellows', 'Reds', 'Short_Shots', 'Long_Shots', 'Target_Shots',
                       'Corners', 'Possesion', 'Centres', 'Attack_Passes', 'Fouls']
    
for stat in stats_check:
            if stat not in home_stats.keys():
                home_stats[stat] = 0
                away_stats[stat] = 0
    
        # Storing the data
match = [date, matchday, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score, home_htscore, away_htscore,
              referee, attedance, home_stats['Yellows'], away_stats['Yellows'],home_stats['Reds'], away_stats['Reds'],
              home_stats['Short_Shots'], away_stats['Short_Shots'], home_stats['Long_Shots'], away_stats['Long_Shots'],
              home_stats['Target_Shots'], away_stats['Target_Shots'], home_stats['Corners'], away_stats['Corners'],
              home_stats['Possesion'], away_stats['Possesion'], home_stats['Centres'], away_stats['Centres'],
              home_stats['Attack_Passes'], away_stats['Attack_Passes'], home_stats['Fouls'], away_stats['Fouls']]
    
season.append(match)
    

    
    # Exporting the data
columns = ['date', 'matchday', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_score', 'away_score',
           'home_htscore', 'away_htscore', 'referee', 'attedance']


for stat in stats_check:
    columns.append(f'home_{stat}')
    columns.append(f'away_{stat}')

dataset = pd.DataFrame(season, columns=columns)
dataset.to_csv('Bundesliga_test.csv', index=False)
print('.csv file exported.')
print(f'Number of errors: {len(errors)}')
print('Errors:\n')
print(errors)
```

Comment: My guess is there is an error in your try block, but you'll never see it unless you debug line by line, or print the exception. change `except:` to `except Exception as e: print(e)` so you can see what is happening

Comment: Suggested command returns nothing but thanks anyway. Unfortunatelly i am not familiar with debugging procedure.

Comment: I'd suggest get familiar with debugging. I just ran the code on my end, and I get a single row dataset fine.

Comment: at least it's working :)

Comment: lol. True. Did you try to add `print(dataset)` right before you use `.to_csv()`, just to check if the dataset is created?

Comment: Omg. Wasn't that so obvious? Print(dataset.to_string()) shows that dataframe doesn't created at all. Very usefull since now i know the problem isn't happen on exporting. Thanks again.

Comment: This is where being able to debug is helpful. You could just put a bunch of print statements at different points to narrow down where the issue is. Or debug line-by line to view the variables as they are stored. If you use an IDE like PyCharm or Spyder, you can easily do that. Otherwise if you are using Jupyter notebooks, then only option you really have is a bunch of print statements in your ciode

Comment: Sure i am not in your league and who am i to debate your knowledge after all, but: Code actually completes without errors. It just scraping zeros instead of real values.Isn't debugging supposed to detect syntax ori logic errors?

Comment: logic errors and/or bugs. With syntax errors, your code just wont run (unless its a syntax error in a `try` block, since if it runs into a syntax error, it'll go into the `exception`. What you want to do in this case with debugging is answer the question of "why is it scraping just zeros"? Could be logic (which since it works on my end, unlikely the case). So something else is happening that is causing this. At what point in the code are we not getting the expected output?

Comment: Once you can figure out at what line in the code you are not getting the intended output, we can troubleshoot and look into why it's happening...and then fix it if we can. Does that make sense?

Comment: Many thanks @chitown88. Based on your tips i managed to spot the troubling lines and correct the code.

Comment: @filpakous, you might want to go ahead and put in your solution below, explaining what the error was and where you fixed it so that it documented and others can see what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

As chitown88 suggested i tried debugging and finally spotted the problem. I had to replace list values with all lowercase in below lists. Fixed and running smoothly.

```
match = [date, matchday, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score, home_htscore, away_htscore, referee, attedance,
          home_stats['possesion'], away_stats['possesion'], home_stats['corners'], away_stats['corners'],
          home_stats['attack_passes'], away_stats['attack_passes'], home_stats['centres'], away_stats['centres'],
          home_stats['short_shots'], away_stats['short_shots'], home_stats['long_shots'], away_stats['long_shots'],
          home_stats['target_shots'], away_stats['target_shots'], home_stats['fouls'], away_stats['fouls'],
          home_stats['yellows'], away_stats['yellows'], home_stats['reds'], away_stats['reds']]
```

and

```
stats_check = ['possesion', 'corners', 'attack_passes', 'centres',
 'short_shots', 'long_shots', 'target_shots', 'fouls', 'yellows', 'reds']
```